# Deadlock because of fulltext index - FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We are having an issue with one of our innodb tables. This table has primary key on integer column (and this one is not auto increment column ) and fulltext key on one of the text columns, Application is executing multiple insert queries and these inserts are not overlapping with Primary key but still we are getting deadlocks show engine innodb status is suggesting FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX reason for Deadlock.
How to fix or avoid this issue apart from retrying when deadlock occurs?

MySQL Version : 5.7.24
Table type : innodb

Also there is no Unique key in the table.